# Anaconda navigator does not start every time my laptop is turned off

Tags: python, startup, anaconda3

The anaconda navigator does not start every time is laptop is turned off. I tried to open Spyder via the anaconda prompt, but then a message occurs see the image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hENBB.png)

However, the required packages are already installed:

(base) C:\Users****>conda install -c anaconda pyqt
Channels:

- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
  Platform: win-64
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

(base) C:\Users****>conda install -c anaconda qtpy
Channels:

- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
  Platform: win-64
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

I tried to delete anaconda and reinstall it, this does work but I did this now 3 times in a week so it is a very time comsuming solution.